# Should we only make network requests in useEffect and not inside of a function only?

Tags: reactjs

For example a user presses a button and a network request is made from only a function and the stateSetter is passed into the function:

```
import {useState, useEffect} from "react";

const handleSearchSubmit = async (
  searchTerm,
  setArticles
) => {
   const url = "www.example.com"

   try {
     const { data } = await url.get("", {
       params: { q: searchTerm },
     });
     setArticles({ articles: data.articles, error: null });
   } catch (err) {
     if (err instanceof Error) {
       setArticles({ articles: null, error: err });
       console.error(err.message);
   }
}

const SearchBar = () => {
  const [fullArticles, setFullArticles] = useState(null)
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useEffect("");

  const handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    handleSearchSubmit(searchTerm, setFullArticles);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
      <div>
        <input
          value={searchTerm}
          onChange={({ target }) => setSearchTerm(target.value)}
          type="text"
        />
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Or should we use our API requests in a useEffect so we are able to use things like the AbortController for cleanup in case a piece of state causes multiple API requests which causes buggy behaviour. Or in the first case, is the use of something like a cleanup unnecessary.

for example:

```
import {useState, useEffect} from "react";

const SearchBar = () => {
  const [fullArticles, setFullArticles] = useState(null)
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
  const [submittedTerm, setSubmittedTerm] = useState("")

  useEffect(() => {
     const controller = new AbortController()
     const signal = controller.signal

     // pass signal down into original search function
     if (submittedTerm) {
        handleSearchSubmit(searchTerm, setFullArticles, signal);
     }

     return () => controller.abort()
  }, [submittedTerm])

  return (
    <form>
      <div>
        <input
          value={searchTerm}
          onChange={({ target }) => setSearchTerm(target.value)}
          onSubmit=(() => setSubmittedTerm(searchTerm))
          type="text"
        />
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};
```

I just want general advise on what is the best practice. Thank you

Edit: Abort controller used in a normal function

```
const mainArticlesSearch = async (
  searchTerm,
  setArticles,
  cancelTokenState
) => {
  const { cancelToken, setCancelToken } = cancelTokenState;

  setCancelToken(axios.CancelToken.source());

  try {
    const { data } = await axiosSearchApi.get("", {
      cancelToken: cancelToken?.token,
      params: { q: searchTerm },
    });

    setArticles({ articles: data.articles, error: null });
  } catch (err) {
      setArticles({ articles: null, error: err });
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  } finally {
    setCancelToken(null);
  }
}

import { useState } from "react";
import { CancelTokenSource } from 'axios'

const Search = () => {
  const [fullArticles, setFullArticles] = useState(null);
  const [cancelToken, setCancelToken] = useState(null);

  const handleSearch = async (searchTerm) => {
    const cancelTokenState = { cancelToken, setCancelToken };

    if (cancelToken) cancelToken.cancel();

    
    await mainArticlesSearch(searchTerm, setFullArticles, cancelTokenState);
  };

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official docs say that you should try to keep side effects in event handlers. Only when you cannot do that should you move them to effects.

[Read](https://react.dev/learn/keeping-components-pure#where-you-_can_-cause-side-effects)

From the docs:

> In React, side effects usually belong inside event handlers. Event handlers are functions that React runs when you perform some action—for example, when you click a button. Even though event handlers are defined inside your component, they don’t run during rendering! So event handlers don’t need to be pure.

> If you’ve exhausted all other options and can’t find the right event
> handler for your side effect, you can still attach it to your returned
> JSX with a useEffect call in your component

In first case API call is called only on submit, so it need not be aborted unless you want to abort it when form unmounts. In second case you are making API call when the input text changes and hence the need to abort.

Note: In any case, to make good parallel comparison you should trigger the both network requests from same event (which is form submission). In 2nd case, you can have a submit button, and when submit event is clicked you can set a variable. That variable can be the dependency of your `useEffect`.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. So in the first case of using an event handler and a user makes two searches fast, how could I signal to the function to abort the first request when the second request comes through without a useEffect? Only inside the function body itself.

Comment: In that case I would suggest to keep a ref of the abort controller. Ref is a way to keep a persistent stable value. Every time you run the method abort the previous ref value and run the method anew, while setting a new value.

Comment: I can write up code if you want, but that should ideally be a new question. Also, you can give it a shot yourself

Comment: I added the additional code for my solution. I used useState to store the AbortController (in axios it is called CancelToken but it works the same). Tell me please, does that look good?

Comment: the first function mainArticlesSearch is called inside of the React component. I hope that makes sense. Or should I have used a useRef?

Comment: If it works for you then good right? One difference between ref and state variable is this only. state variable will cause an unnecessary re-render. ref would not do that